# How to keep the markdown header when rendering from qmd to md in Quarto?

Tags: r-markdown, markdown, quarto

When I render a quarto document (.qmd) to markdown (.md) with

```
quarto render document.qmd -t md
```

I would like to keep the original markdown metadata header (between the `---` markings). How can I make quarto keep it? It cuts it off, but I need it for further processing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`md` is not a format for Quarto (or Pandoc) as mentioned by one of the authors: https://github.com/quarto-dev/quarto-cli/issues/5830#issuecomment-1578748592

`quarto render document.qmd -t markdown` will convert your document and keep the YAML header. `markdown` is a Pandoc format but not supported by Quarto, see GitHub issue https://github.com/quarto-dev/quarto-cli/issues/5830.

It's recommended to use a officially supported format, for example `quarto render mwe.qmd --to hugo`.

Input:

```
---
author: Jane Doe
title: Foo
extra: lorem ipsum
---

Bar.
```

Output (`quarto render mwe.qmd --to hugo`):

```
---
author: Jane Doe
title: Foo
extra: lorem ipsum
---

Bar.
```

Output (`quarto render mwe.qmd --to markdown`):

```
---
author:
- Jane Doe
extra: lorem ipsum
title: Foo
toc-title: Table of contents
---

Bar.
```

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution could be using `post_render` to run a script file that will extract the YAML front matter from the qmd file and then add it to the generated md file.

**_quarto.yml**

```yaml
project: 
  post-render: parse_yaml.R
```

**parse_yaml.R**

````r
library(ymlthis)

input_file <- "test.qmd"
output_file <- "test.md"

yaml <- rmarkdown::yaml_front_matter(input_file)
yaml_str <- as.character(asis_yaml_output(as_yml(yaml)))
yaml_cleaned <- gsub("```yaml\n|\n```", replacement = "", yaml_str)

body <- paste0(readLines(output_file), collapse = "\n")
full <- paste0(yaml_cleaned, "\n\n", body)

writeLines(full, output_file)
````

**test.qmd**

````markdown
---
title: "testing"
author: None
date: last_modified
format: gfm
---

## Quarto

Quarto enables you to weave together content and executable code into a finished document.

## Running Code

When you click the **Render** button a document will be generated that includes both
content and the output of embedded code. You can embed code like this:

```{r}
1 + 1
```

You can add options to executable code like this 

```{r}
#| echo: false
2 * 2
```

The `echo: false` option disables the printing of code (only output is displayed).
````

Keep all the three files above in a same directory, then run the following in that directory,

```bash
quarto render test.qmd -t md
```